# IE11 - InsertRow always appending rows as firstrow

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, internet-explorer-11

We are migrating our project to IE11. Below code is working fine in IE8. But in IE11, it is inserting rows always as fist row not at the end.

```
var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
rowcount  = table.rows.length;
row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
```

Comment: Try `parent.appendChild(el)`.

Comment: Have you tried not supplying a rowcount? "If index is -1 or equal to the number of rows, the row is appended as the last row"

Comment: Yes I'm curious too about the thought process behind supplying the row index

Comment: Does it have to work in both IE8 AND IE11?